# How to strip C++ style single line comments (`// ...`)

Tags: regex, parsing, comments, dsl

For a small DSL I'm writing I'm looking for a regex to match a comment string at the end of the like the `//` syntax of C++.
The simple case:

```
someVariable = 12345; // assignment
```

Is trivial to match but the problem starts when I have a string in the same line:

```
someFunctionCall("Hello // world"); // call with a string
```

The `//` in the string should not match as a comment

---

**EDIT** - The thing that compiles the DSL is not mine. It's a black box as far as I'm which I don't want to change and it doesn't support comments. I just want to add a thin wrapper to make it support comments.

Comment: Another useful test case: `someFunctionCall("Hello World"); // comment // shenanigans!`

Comment: If you're creating a tokenizer for your DSL, it would be easy to filter out comments on that stage. Trying to do this with regex is going to result in a buggy solution, especially if quotes can be escaped inside string literals.

Comment: Just had a brainwave. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398715/regex-for-matching-a-comment-at-the-end-of-a-line/7398825#7398825)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Since you are effectively preprocessing a sourcefile, why don't you use an existing preprocessor? If the language is sufficiently similar to C/C++ (especially regarding quoting and string literals), you will be able to just use `cpp -P`:

```
 echo 'int main() { char* sz="Hello//world"; /*profit*/ } // comment' | cpp -P
```

Output: `int main() { char* sz="Hello//world"; }`

---

*Other ideas:*

Use a proper lexer/parser instead

Have a look at

- CoCo/R (available for Java, C++, C#, etc.)
- ANTLR (idem)
- Boost Spirit (with Spirit Lex to make it even easier to strip the comments)

All suites come with sample grammars that parse C, C++ or a subset thereof

Comment: The compiler is actually not mine. it's a black box which I don't want to change and it doesn't support comments. I just want to add a thin wrapper to make it support comments.

Comment: Even better. You don't need a full grammar then.

Comment: **Edit** use a preprocessor. There are several standalone preprocessor implementations available (see e.g. Boost Wave)

Answer (score 2):

> ***shoosh wrote:***
>
> **EDIT** - The thing that compiles the DSL is not mine. It's a black box as far as I'm which I don't want to change and it doesn't support comments. I just want to add a thin wrapper to make it support comments.

In that case, create a very simple lexer that matches one of three tokens:

1. `// ...` comments
2. string literals: `" ... "`
3. or, if none of the above matches, match any single character

Now, while you iterate ov er these 3 different type of tokens, simply print tokens (2) and (3) to the stdout (or to a file) to get the uncommented version of your source file.

A demo with GNU Flex:

example input file, **in.txt**:

```c
someVariable = 12345; // assignment
// only a comment
someFunctionCall("Hello // world"); // call with a string
someOtherFunctionCall("Hello // \" world"); // call with a string and 
                                            // an escaped quote
```

The lexer grammar file, **demo.l**:

```c
%%
"//"[^\r\n]*             { /* skip comments */ }
"\""([^"]|[\\].)*"\""    {printf("%s", yytext);}
.                        {printf("%s", yytext);}
%%
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while(yylex() != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

And to run the demo, do:

```
flex demo.l 
cc lex.yy.c -lfl
./a.out < in.txt
```

which will print the following to the console:

```
someVariable = 12345; 

someFunctionCall("Hello // world"); 
someOtherFunctionCall("Hello // \" world");
```

### EDIT

I'm not really familiar with C/C++, and just saw @sehe's recommendation of using a pre-processor. That looks to be a far better option than creating your own (small) lexer. But I think I'll leave this answer since it shows how to handle this kind of stuff if no pre-processor is available (for whatever reason: perhaps `cpp` doesn't recognise certain parts of the DSL?).